# How to show window contents while dragging in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: themes, aero, windows-server-2008-r2

I just installed Windows Server 2008 R2, including the Desktop Experience feature, and activated the Themes service. I've activated Aero.

I have everything there, except that when I drag windows, I only see the border of the window as I'm dragging.  In other/older SKUs of Windows, there was a checkbox that I think said "Show Window Contents While Dragging", but I can't find such a checkbox on this OS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to System (Press <kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>) then click "Advanced system settings" on the left.

The top option should be Performance and you should be able to tick as many of the Visual Effects as you want.

If using as a Workstation, you may not want too many of them, but if using as a standard desktop, you may want the "Adjust for best appearance" selection.

[image]

(fifth one up in that picture)

Comment: Ta. Didn't know about [Win]+[Break]